# Differences in erasing an entity from a list in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to erase an entity from a list in two cases. In the first case the following worked just fine, where I have a list of pairs from which I want to erase a certain one:

```
bool remove(std::list<std::pair<std::string, size_t>>& myList, std::string const& name) {

for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    if(i->first == name) {
        myList.erase(i);
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}
```

Here the pair gets removed from the list as it should, but when I have a list of structs it does not work as in the following:

```
void remove(std::list<myStruct>& myList , const std::string& name) {

for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    if(i->name == name) {
        myList.erase(i);
    }
}
```

The program crashes in the erase part. Only if I plug in `myList.erase(i++)` then it works. Why is this??

Have I done something foul in the first case and it just happened to work, but then in the second case it does not? I can not understand the reason.

Comment: You show two loops. One `return`s after an erase, one doesn't, but you conclude the crash is because the second one involves structs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first loop removes an entry from the list and stops.

```
for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    if(i->first == name) {
        myList.erase(i);
        return true;
    }
}
```

while your second loop continues looking for matching elements:

```
for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end(); i++) {
    if(i->name == name) {
        myList.erase(i);
    }
}
```

When you erase `i` from `myList`, `i` becomes invalid - we have no idea what it references now that the element it *was* talking about has gone away and may have been deleted, returned to the os and it's memory used by another thread.

The very next thing you do is `i++` which is undefined behavior, since `i` is an invalid iterator.

The `erase` operator returns the next valid iterator, so you could write this:

```
for (auto i = myList.begin(); i != myList.end();) {
    if(i->name == name)
        i = myList.erase(i);
    else
        i++;
}
```

Or you could write:

```
void remove(std::list<myStruct>& myList , const std::string& name) {
    myList.remove_if([&](const myStruct& it) { return it.name == name; });
}
```

or if your compiler supports C++14

```
void remove(std::list<myStruct>& myList , const std::string& name) {
    myList.remove_if([&](auto& it) { return it.name == name; });
}
```

As in

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>

struct A {
    std::string name_;
    A(const char* name) : name_(name) {}
};

void dump(const std::list<A>& list) {
    for (auto&& a : list) {
        std::cout << a.name_ << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::list<A> myList { { "hello", "pizza", "world", "pizza" } };
    dump(myList);
    const std::string name = "pizza";
    myList.remove_if([&](const A& it){ return it.name_ == name; });
    dump(myList);
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/SaWejv

Comment: What's C++17 in the C++17 example? C++14 introduced generic lambdas.

Comment: @krzaq Thanks, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

You're working on an invalidated iterator. That's undefined behavior. That's why `erase` returns a valid iterator.

If you want to only erase the first matching element, use `find_if` and then erase if the returned iterator isn't equal to `end()`.

```
auto it = find_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), [&name](auto const& p){
    return p.first == name;
});

if(it == myList.end()){
    return false;
}

myList.erase(it);
return true;
```

Otherwise, just use erase-remove idiom and be wary for its pitfalls (erase will happily accept 1 argument, but it'll call a different overload):

```
auto it = remove_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), [&name](auto const& p){
    return p.first == name;
});

myList.erase(it, myList.end());
```

The above is a generic version (will work if you change `myList`'s type to `vector` for example), but as per [ksfone's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39811428/2456565), `std::list<T>` implements member function template `remove_if`:

```
myList.remove_if([&name](auto const& p){
    return p.first == name;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`erase()` invalidates the erased iterator. The `for` loop then attempts to increment the invalidated iterator, resulting in undefined behavior, and a crash.

The correct way to do this, actually, would be:

```
i=erase(i);
```

rather than using post-increment.

Answer (score 1):

I'll avoid repeating what others have stated and instead suggest a more elegant solution via the erase-remove idiom:

```
myList.erase(std::remove_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(), [&name](auto& el) {
    return el.first == name;
}), myList.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the iterator breaks when you remove an item, but in the first case you are returning back so the error never occurs in the next iteration. In any way it's not a matter of your struct.